# phpMyAdmin login page not working

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin

Centos with PHP 5.3.10

I have php error reporting set to E_ALL | E_STRICT but am getting no errors.

It doesn't matter whether I put in correct or incorrect username/password combos. The result is always the same: the login page reloads and does not display any errors.

I have heard that this problem can be caused by a full disk. But my disk is only 63% full.

Also, phpMyAdmin was working before. All of a sudden it stopped working. Nothing changed as far as I know.

Oh, and finally, I was sometimes getting this error displayed on the webpage after trying to log in:

```
phpMyAdmin - Error
"Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly."
```

But for the last day or so, no errors (in logs or on screen).

Comment: Nothing. Nothing in logs at all. No errors.

Comment: Have you changed any directories' permissions or any other access settings (`chmod`, `chown`, `chgrp`, etc)?

Comment: Coincidentally, I just found the answer and your suggestion is correct, although I just read it afterwards. I wish I had talked to you yesterday. The problem was that I changed the gid for apache and so it no longer had access to the /var/lib/php/session/ directory. I changed ownership of that folder and now everything works! The weird thing is that cart items were being saved and I don't see how that could be without sessions functioning. This is why I didn't think sessions were the problem. But they were.

Comment: Maybe your application has a different way to deal with data which is supposed to be in a session. DB, localStorage, etc